# Task :unimodules-react-native-adapter:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, apk

When i try to convert react native app to apk, I can create output folder but then I get this error:

> Task :unimodules-react-native-adapter:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':unimodules-react-native-adapter:compileReleaseKotlin'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':unimodules-react-native-adapter:releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not download nativeloader-0.8.0.jar (com.facebook.soloader:nativeloader:0.8.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/soloader/nativeloader/0.8.0/nativeloader-0.8.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/soloader/nativeloader/0.8.0/nativeloader-0.8.0.jar'.
> > jcenter.bintray.com
> Could not download okhttp-urlconnection-3.12.1.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.12.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection/3.12.1/okhttp-urlconnection-3.12.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection/3.12.1/okhttp-urlconnection-3.12.1.jar'.
> > jcenter.bintray.com
> Could not download okhttp-3.12.1.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.12.1/okhttp-3.12.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.12.1/okhttp-3.12.1.jar'.
> > jcenter.bintray.com

Comment: Any updates on this one?

Comment: Could you solve it? I have same problem.

Comment: Not yet. I publish my app then i test it in internal testing mode.